# How do I use a C++ header-file in a setuptools.Extension?

Tags: c++, cython, header-files, setuptools

I have a file `gzstream.h` I need to use in my setuptools.Extension.

If I try with .h

```
 Extension(
    "epic2.src.cpp_read_files",
    ["epic2/src/cpp_read_files.pyx", "epic2/src/gzstream.h"],
    language="c++", /// ...
```

I get the error

```
error: unknown file type '.h' (from 'epic2/src/gzstream.h')
```

If I try with .cpp it works:

```
 Extension(
    "epic2.src.cpp_read_files",
    ["epic2/src/cpp_read_files.pyx", "epic2/src/gzstream.cpp"],
    language="c++", /// ...
```

but now I get a different, but predictable error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'epic2/src/gzstream.cpp'
```

I cannot just rename the .h file to gzstream.cpp, because then I get the error:

```
epic2/src/read_files.cpp:202:10: fatal error: 'gzstream.h' file not found
#include "gzstream.h"
```

While I do not have a minimal reproducible example, I have a reproducible example:

https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/epic2

```
git clone https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/epic2.git
cd epic2
pip install pysam
python setup.py install # now you should see my header-woes.
```

Comment: Do you actually need to list it in setup.py? Normally including it in your .pyx causes it to be included in the generated .c file. You typically don't need to compile it separately

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I was cargo-culting when I created this project. Never used C++ much XD. Now I do not get that error but a different one. Will create new question.

Comment: I guess your comment can be an answer btw. Perhaps explain more or quote something from the docs about Extension if you feel your comment would be too trivial as an answer.